# How to release an NSMutableDictionary Instance Variable properly, with nested dictionaries, in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutabledictionary, nested

I have an Objective-C class that looks something like:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict;
}
```

Its setter method looks like:

```
- (void) setADict: (NSMutableDictionary *) newDict
{
    [aDict release];
    [newDict retain];
    aDict = newDict;
}
```

I've created an instance of the object, put data into aDict, and now want to get rid of the object, cleaning up its memory in the process.  Two questions:

1) Should I release **aDict** in **myClass**'s *dealloc* method, as shown?

```
[aDict release];
```

=============================================================================

2) I've nested several children dictionaries into **aDict**, represented by **keyA** and **keyB**, like so:

```
// aDict:
{
    keyA =     {
        keyA1 = "Hello world";
        keyA2 = 1234;
    };
    keyB =     {
        keyB1 = Earth;
        keyB2 = 25000;
    };
}
```

Will a **[aDict release]** message "propagate down the chain" and cleanup all children dictionaries inside of aDict, including *their* key/value objects?  Or, do I have to do something else to get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Collection objects retain the things they're collecting, so when the collection is deallocated, it balances the retain with a release.

Then if one of the dictionaries it was holding onto is deallocated, it will also release its key/value pairs, since the dictionary is a collection, and collection objects retain the things they're collecting.

The same holds true for arrays and sets.

However, you have a bug in your code.  You have:

```
- (void) setADict: (NSMutableDictionary *) newDict
{
    [aDict release];
    [newDict retain];
    aDict = newDict;
}
```

Consider the case when `newDict` is the same object as `aDict`.  Then you release the dictionary, it is deallocated, and then you attempt to retain it, but whoops!  It's no longer there.

There are three alternatives to fixing this.  Here they are:

```
    - (void) setADict: (NSMutableDictionary *) newDict
    {
        [aDict autorelease];
        [newDict retain];
        aDict = newDict;
    }

    - (void) setADict: (NSMutableDictionary *) newDict
    {
      if (aDict != newDict) {
        [aDict release];
        [newDict retain];
        aDict = newDict;
      }
    }

    - (void) setADict: (NSMutableDictionary *) newDict
    {
        [newDict retain];
        [aDict release];
        aDict = newDict;
    }
```

I'd say the third one is simplest, the second one is fastest over time, and the first is *meh*.  The first will clutter up your autorelease pools (which may or may not lead to memory bloat).  The second and third are equivalent in terms of safety and property memory management.  However, the second will save you unnecessary method calls if you happen to be setting the same dictionary over itself.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, and thanks so much for catching the bug! :) I'm looking at "Cocoa Programming for Mac OX X" by Hillegass and he has the exact same three mem-management idioms listed in there. Stupid me reversed the retain/release ordering, ha ha. I won't forget it now, promise!

Answer (score 2):

**`NSMutableDictionary` will release all objects (values) on release.**

`NSMutableDictionary` copies key and send retain to value for each key/value pair that you added. Cocoa practice is that when something retains reference then it is responsible for releasing it.

[See NSMutableDictionary reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-9552)

> Methods that add entries to
>   dictionaries—whether as part of
>   initialization (for all dictionaries)
>   or during modification (for mutable
>   dictionaries)—copy each key argument
>   (keys must conform to the NSCopying
>   protocol) and add the copies to the
>   dictionary. Each corresponding value
>   object receives a retain message to
>   ensure that it won’t be deallocated
>   before the dictionary is through with
>   it.